# Is it a good idea to add "/error" route to permitAll()?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I am trying to implement JWT authentication. This is going to be the only form of authentication in the app. Using Spring security I've implemented JWT validation filter and added it to the chain before AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.

```java
public class JwtTokenFilter extends BasicAuthenticationFilter {
    private final JwtTokenService jwtTokenService;

    public JwtTokenFilter(JwtTokenService jwtTokenService,
                          AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        super(authenticationManager);
        this.jwtTokenService = jwtTokenService;
    }

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(
            @NonNull HttpServletRequest request,
            @NonNull HttpServletResponse response,
            @NonNull FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String initialToken = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        String token;

        if(initialToken == null || initialToken.isEmpty()){
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            return;
        }

        if (initialToken.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            token = initialToken.substring(7);
        }
        else {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            return;
        }

        if(token.isEmpty()){
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            return;
        }

        try {
            String userId = jwtTokenService.getUserIdFromToken(token);
            String userLogin = jwtTokenService.getUserLoginFromToken(token);
            String role = jwtTokenService.getRoleFromToken(token);
            Date expiration = jwtTokenService.getExpirationDateFromToken(token);

            if(!userLogin.isEmpty() && !userId.isEmpty() && !role.isEmpty() && expiration != null){
                JwtUser user = new JwtUser(userId, userLogin, role, expiration);
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, null, user.getAuthorities());
                auth.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));

                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            logger.error("Error while parsing jwt: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        finally {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    }
}
```

The filter works, with valid token it successfully creates UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken and allows access. But after this i receive log saying "Securing POST /error" and another filter chain starts which doesn't have the same JWT token, so my filter does nothing in the new chain and i get AnonymousAuthenticationToken, which obviously leads to 401 Unathorized error.

So even valid token results in 401 Unauthorized.

Setting `http.authorizeHttpRequests().requestMatchers("/error").permitAll()`
in `securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http)` method solves the issue.

Is it secure to set `.requestMatchers("/error").permitAll()`?

If not, what could be the issue? Is there something wrong with my JWT validation logic implementation?

Comment: Hi& Welcome! "Is it secure to set .requestMatchers("/error").permitAll()?" for debugging/understanding/"fixing": definitely! For production: rather not!;)

Comment: @xerx593 Thanks for the answer! If disabling security for "/error" isn't a good idea, I wonder what is wrong with my code? My first guess was that it needed AuthenticationManager, so i implemented my own AuthenticationManager bean and it still doesn't work.